# disable spring formlogin and basic auth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following spring boot 2.0 config but I am still getting the basic auth login screen.  I DO NOT want to disable all spring security like almost every post on the internet suggests.  I only want to stop the form login page and basic auth so I can use my own.
I have seen all the suggestions with permitAll and exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class} and a few others that I can't remember anymore.  Those are not what I want.  I want to use spring security but I wan my config not Spring Boots.  Yes I know many people are going to say this is a duplicate but I disagree because all the other answers are to disable spring security completely and not just stop the stupid login page.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class CustomSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private final RememberMeServices rememberMeService;
private final AuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;
@Value("${server.session.cookie.secure:true}")
private boolean useSecureCookie;

@Inject
public CustomSecurity(RememberMeServices rememberMeService, AuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider) {
    super(true);
    this.rememberMeService = rememberMeService;
    this.bouncerAuthProvider = bouncerAuthProvider;
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/**").antMatchers("/webjars/**").antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")
       .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).headers().frameOptions().disable();
    http.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider).authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeService).useSecureCookie(useSecureCookie);
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new ForbiddenEntryPoint());
}
}
```

Comment: so you want to redirect to your own login page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to your own login page, i can show your sample code and configuration

remove the `http.httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable();`, you should set your own login page to redirect instead of disable form login

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/my_login").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/my_login");
    }
```

then create your own `LoginController`

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/my_login")
    public ModelAndView myLogin() {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
}
```

you can specified the `login` with `thymeleaf` view resolver

Comment: No, the login page is taken care of by an API manager and the custom authProvider checks out the necessary data to validate that the user is logged in.  So all i need to do is get rid of all the login/basic auth nonsense that spring is forcing down my throat.

Comment: i am not very clear about your mean, let's discuss from start, if a user is visit a protected url without logged in, what's your expectation?